# Is there an OpenSource BASIC interpreter in Ruby/Python?

Tags: python, ruby, interpreter

I want something simple in order to experiment/hack. I've created a lot interpreters/compilers for c and I just want something simple. A basic BASIC :D

If you don't know any (I've done my google search...), yacc/bison is the only way?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of these listed in [TheFreeCountry](http://www.thefreecountry.com/compilers/basic.shtml) are acceptable?  None of them are in Python, but I should think that starting from [XBLite](http://www.xblite.com/)  might be more helpful than starting from Yacc/Bison/[PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/).

Also, [Vb2py](http://vb2py.sourceforge.net/) might be a better starting position than PLY.

If you must go the PLY route, however, consider the [MOLE Basic](http://www.xs4all.nl/~merty/mole/) grammar as a starting point rather than trying to roll your own from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

[PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) is a great parser-creation library for Python. It has a simple BASIC interpreter as one of its example scripts. You could start there.

Answer (score 1):

I also don't know a basic interpreter under ruby, but given enough time and interest ruby easily "supports" writing an interpreter for any language you like: [Agile DSL Development
in Ruby](http://obiefernandez.com/presentations/obie_fernandez-agile_dsl_development_in_ruby.pdf) . I must admit that this approach comes with some investment of time. :(
At the end of the presentation are some links to further readings regarding DSLs.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to also examine [the Parrot virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrot_virtual_machine) which, according to wikipedia today, has some BASIC support.

Answer (score 0):

a miniBasic in ruby is available [here](http://rockit.sourceforge.net/). Rockit seems WAY more fun that racc.

Answer (score -1):

There is pybasic (python basic), rockit-minibasic (rubybasic).

To make these able to use the gui, then one has to develop extensions with kivy and shoes gui toolkits for pybasic and rockit-minibasic respectively and similarly prima gui for perlbasic if ever exists.